# What command or key combination produces ESC Key's Action in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-interface

I am writing a script file to perform certain actions and when I invoke the script file the following actions should be performed sequentially

1. Navigate to a folder.
2. Open an existing file using vi editor **vi myfile.properties**
3. move to specific line and update the content.
4. Hit **ESC** key on keyboard and save+exit the file using **wq!** and enter.

Now I need some help to do line 3 and 4 in script format.
I read in some websites pressing letter **'a'** on keyboard will let us enter write mode from command mode but what is the unix command that I should use after vi filename to get edit mode?

Also what's the command to exit out of edit mode? With the help of keyboard I will hit ESC key but now I need the script to do the same.

Comment: If the eventual goal is simply to modify a properties file, you'd be far better off looking at either sed or awk to achieve this. Automating VI is no simple feat although you may be able to achieve this using the `expect` command (can't say I've ever tried this though so cannot comment on how easy / hard it would be)

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing your script in vi, use the keycombination `CTRL-v` followed by `ESC`. This will result in the ESC key action.
Something like

```
vi example.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 <<END
o
I write this on a new line so you have 2 newlines, from o and the enter after o
*** key combination for ESC showing something like ^] ***
:wq
END
```

Comment: I am not clear with your solution can you please explain this.

Let's say the first command in my file is **vi myfile.properties** to open the file in editor and now I need the next command to go to editor mode from command mode. In Manual operation I simply hit either insert button or 'a' on keyboard to start editing.
What should be the next command to get the file in editor mode

Comment: Everything between `<<END` and later `END` is seen as your vi input (google: search for `here document`), no space or tab before or after END.
You start in the vi command mode, using `o` you switch to the edit mode, with the `escaped escape` you come back to the command mode, save the file and done.
A little spooky: reconsider your requirements and look for another solution.